# Ubuntu 16.04 log in loop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, upstart

I uninstalled json-c library on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using `# make uninstall`
and removed all rest json-c with:

```
# find / -name "*json-c*" -exec rm -rf {} /;
```

after reboot, can not log into system - Log In loop

```
# cat ~/.xsession-error
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
/sbin/upstart: error while loading shared libraries: libjson-c.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried to reinstall json-c, it gives me a library named libjson-c.so.3 but not 2.

And system is under systemd, right?

```
# ps -e | grep systemd
1 ? 00:00:02 systemd
```

UPDATE:
here is how i fixed broken package

```
# apt-get download libjson-c2
# dpkg -i libjson-c2ww
```

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to use specific StackExchange site called Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a user question? I cannot tell.

Comment: [This has now been cross-posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918247/upstart-error-while-loading-shared-library) at Ask Ubuntu. OP, please always update your posts with cross-posting URLs, to make it easier for readers to reduce duplicate answering effort.

Comment: My first question, will do my best. It is a question related to Operation System, not strictly programming, rather something between. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Your find command removed more than just what was installed from the source install.

```
# apt -y install libjson-c2
```